# How to get JDBC SQL Count result as int?

Tags: sql, jdbc

If i run this code:

```
ResultSet rs1 = Stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM genericEmployees;");
```

It returns a ResultSet with the number of employees are in that table.

How do i get that as an int, instead of as a ResultSet?

How do i convert a Resultset into an int to use?

Comment: What database is this on?

Comment: You retrieve your `int` from `ResultSet` the usual way.

Comment: Its an SQL database and what is the usual way?

Comment: Your `ResultSet` returns one row with one column, so iterate through the `ResultSet` and get the first column of the `ResultSet` as an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (rs1.next()) {
  int count = rs1.getInt (1);
}
```

That's the usual way.

Comment: This code is missing a semi colon,  because I couldn't find that key on my Android keyboard :-)